# Woocommerce, How to check current page is order tracking page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on Woocommerce and want to trigger some code on **Order Tracking page** only. Is there any function like **is_cart()** or **is_shop()** to check that the current page is **Order Tracking** Page or not?

My code snippet to identify other Woocommerce page is similar as below :

```
if(is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_account_page()){

      //do this things..

}

if( *order-tracking-page* ){

     // do this things

}
```

Please let me know if there is any method or function to identify the current page is order tracking page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any built-in function to identify the order tracking page.  you can use wordpress global variable '$pagename' that contains always the page name in which you are. So try this , it might help you. Like:

```
if($pagename == 'your-page-name'){
   // do what you want here.
}
```

Comment: Great!! it's working. Thanks :)